# aurelia contacts app fatal error on installation

Tags: aurelia

Have just tried to do a simple install of app-contacts and get the following error on "npm install" ....

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory

I am running supported versions of node, npm, and jspm.

Running on a high spec Windows machine. Why would a simple Aurelia app cause a high spec windows machine to fall over like this>

Comment: What versions of node and npm are you running? JSPM isn't used by app-contacts any more as it is based on our CLI.

Comment: I just downloaded the latest release of the app and ran npm install no problem, btw.